# Gatsby Image Not Working - Images Blurry on Deploy or does not show up at all

Tags: github-pages, gatsby, gatsby-image

**Project Description:** Using Gatsby to create a portfolio website to showcase my JavaScript projects.

**Problem:** I cannot get images to load using gatsby-image in my deployment to github pages - it works on my local machine. If I use childImageSharp.fixed it is blurry and if I use childImageSharp.noBase64 the image does not show up at all.

**What I have tried:** I have tried deleting my public and .cache folders and rebuilding (many times) - didn't work. I have tried using older versions of Gatsby and gatsby-images this didn't work and it seems to break other things. I've tried improving the quality but changing some settings but it didn't work. These are all things I have tried from other StackOverflow posts I've been reading the past couple of days.

*Note: I also tried to not use Gatsby Images and you will see a lot of other data in my query even without Gatsby images I cannot get the images to show up not broken. But using gatsby images it's either blurry or blank as I stated above.

**Github repo:** https://github.com/mk0b/gatsby-portfolio-site

**Live Github Pages Site:** https://mk0b.github.io/gatsby-portfolio-site/

**Notes on structure - My graphQL query is in Projects.js and is passing down all the info to Project.js which then uses gatsby image.

Thank you for any help/guidance in advance!!

Comment: What is the size of the image width and height props you are passing in? That could be reason why it is blurry because the image is rendered small.

Comment: @Aquasar I just saw this! 

I don't remember what the sizes were but I had tried to alter them because of some threads I was reading and it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gatsby, "gatsby--image" not showing image when project is "build" but showing properly while in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826664/gatsby-gatsby-image-not-showing-image-when-project-is-build-but-showing-pr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone in one my of my slack communities suggested I try Netlify instead of github pages and the images work with Netlify deploy. So this is not resolved but is no longer pressing.

Answer (score 4):

For github pages, you need to specify the public path separately.

gatsby-config.js

```
pathPrefix: '/gatsby-portfolio-site',
```

package.json

```
"build": "gatsby build --prefix-paths",
```

Good Luck!